# Unable to change backgroundView property on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` and I am trying to set a background image using the backgroundView property based on if there is any data in the CollectionView or not. I have navigation which will change the data, and reloads the collection view (calling `[self.collectionView reloadData]`). For some reason I am getting very strange results. Firstly, sometimes when I set the property it appears on top of the collectionView cells and obscured them. Secondly when I try to change the property it does not change on screen.
This is driving me nuts ! It seemed such a simple thing to implement!

So in Code. In`viewDidLoad` for the `UICollectionViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self loadSections];
[self setupBackgroundView;
}
```

The Load sections method just loads the data I am using for the collection view, which then also calls a method to set the background view which decides what view to add based on if there is any data as below:

```
- (void)loadSections {
[self loadPictures];
[self setupBackgroundImage];
}

- (void)setupBackgroundImage {
if ([self.sections count] == 0 || !self.sections) {
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TakePhoto"]];
}
else {
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = nil;
}
}
```

Now when the view first loads, if there is no data and so no cells to display the background Image comes up correctly. I then change data and I now have some cells to show, the setupBackgroundImage is called and I can verify that the backgroundImage Property is set to nil (I have even breakpointed here and checked the value and it is nil). BUT the background image is still visible.

Additionally if I change the nil to another image this new image is never shown.

And even more strange. If I have some cells displayed and set a background image then this image is displayed neatly behind the cells. If I then reloadData with a new data set, then image is displayed in front of the cells, obscuring them. I have no idea how this happens as then background view should be behind all the others.

Does anyone know why this is happening. Is it getting cached anywhere? or am I just doing something silly ? I am at a total loss here - have spent more time on this than writing the custom layout that it uses!

Comment: Any chance multiple `UICollectionViews` are being created and added as subviews?  That would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment bobnoble. I also wondered if this might have happened. As far as I can tell, from both checking through the code and from running Instruments Allocation tool, then no, there is just one UICollectionView.

Comment: Any chance your setupBackgroundImage is sometimes being called on a thread other than the main thread?

Comment: A collection view is a subclass of UIScrollView. The point of a UIScrollView is to translate the frame position of subviews according to scrolling dynamics. As such the expected meaning and behaviour of a backgroundView is ambiguous (is it on the scrollview content plane or a view corresponding to the background of the scrollView itself?) and the normal backgroundView property of a UIView is not supported.  Additionally for performance reasons Apple would not want to encourage setting a "static" background content to appear under scrolling views positioned on the content plane.

Comment: You can set a static background image if you specifically want to, by adding a view and ensuring its position is updated with each call to scrollViewDidScroll so that it remains fixed in relative to the scrollView content offset:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution to my specific problem, although i still don't understand why I am getting the strange behaviour mentioned in my question, at least this way allows me to change the background image.

Basically I create a property to hold a `UIImageView` and then set the `UICollectionView` to this property. I can then change the image in the image view via the property I have saved.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self loadSections];
    self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = self.backgroundImageView;
}

- (void)setupBackgroundImage {
    if ([self.sections count] == 0 || !self.sections) {
        self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TakePhoto"];
    }
    else {
            self.backgroundImageView.image = nil;
    }
}

- (void)loadSections {
    [self loadPictures];
    [self setupBackgroundImage];
}
```

Where `self.backgroundImageView` is the property I have defined for the purpose of keeping a reference to the background view.

If anyone has any insight into the strange behaviour mentioned in the question I'd be really interested to hear it!

Comment: are you sure it's not your background image format issue? I had same issue when I tried to set up the collecitoview backgroudimage. It works fine after I changed to use an other picture with png format. self.CollectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageVIew alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newPic"]];

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
self.collectionView.backgroundView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.collectionView.bounds]; 
UIImageView *imgVW=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TakePhoto"]];
[self.collectionView.backgroundView addSubView:imgVW];
```

Answer (score 1):

as pointed out in this post [UICollectionView’s backgroundView property is horribly broken](http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/11/uicollectionviews-backgroundview-property-is-horribly-broken/)

one can have a bitter reading when cmd+click on UICollectionViewCell class.

```
// The background view is a subview behind all other views.
// If selectedBackgroundView is different than backgroundView, it will be placed above the background view and animated in on selection.
@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) UIView *backgroundView;
```

your new one is inserted below the old one. just spent my last hour debugging and swearing a lot trying to find out what is not working.

just use removeFromSuperview

Comment: self.backgroundView?.removeFromSuperview() doesnt do it for me and the old view is still there, even when calling removeFromSuperview() on it

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know if this is related but I found this after a long search. Hope this saves somebody some time.

As with a UICollectionView a UITableView has a background view that is build before AutoLayout. If you use autoLayout you should make sure the backgroundView has a frame. Otherwise is will disappear. In your cell subclass you can do:

```
    -(void)setBackgroundView:(UIView *)backgroundView
{
    super.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    self.backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.backgroundView autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i needed to have 2 different views and switch between them... it looks like the backgroundView is quite broken, but i managed to get the desired functionality like this

```
backgroundLoadingView?.isHidden = true
noItemsBackgroundView?.isHidden = false
backgroundView = noItemsBackgroundView
```

meaning i have to hide / show the desired, and also assign the desired view to the property

to switch to the loadingView

```
    backgroundLoadingView?.isHidden = false
    noItemsBackgroundView?.isHidden = true
    backgroundView = backgroundLoadingView
```

and to hide it completely

```
backgroundView?.isHidden = true
```

alt. you could have different views in one view, that you assign to the background view and than switch its subviews around